# Opening Files/DocumentsUI via Intent given the Path

Tags: android, android-external-storage, android-8.1-oreo

My code:

```
Uri selectedUri = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/Music");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(selectedUri, "*/*");
intent.setType("*/*");
intent.setClassName("com.android.documentsui", "com.android.documentsui.files.FilesActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

But its always opens only the Downloads tab, not Music on my sdcard.

Comment: try changing type to mp3 or other music format

Comment: I want to open any folder, Music is only a example.

Comment: Your code will crash on lots of devices, as there is no requirement for any device to support that `Intent` structure. Hacking into other apps is never a reliable solution, and your `setComponent()` is trying to hack into the Storage Access Framework UI. Moreover, `/sdcard/Music` is not a valid `Uri` (it has no scheme), and the Storage Access Framework does not work with filesystem paths. Use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` and allow the user to choose the location that the user wants.

Comment: Scheme fixed. It's okay if it's crashing, it must only run on AOSP. I doesn't should view an directory picker, it should open any folder in DocumentsUI. No other file manager. And I doesn't find a setComponent() in my Code

Comment: Could you get this working?

Comment: Nope as SAF is not supposed to work like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Action:
android.intent.action.VIEW

Data:
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3ADownload%2FMyDir

Mime:
vnd.android.document/directory

Flags:
These don't seem to be critical
```

This intent will invoke DocumentsUI (and likely other file managers) and if you pick DocumentsUI it will open to the provided path. %3A for the first / and %2F for subsequent / as you nest into the file tree.

Cheers!

Comment: It's been way too long for me and I don't need it anymore - but thanks anyway :) nice for future reference